# Create multiple pdf files from same tex file

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have multiple data files (result_a.csv, result_b.csv, ..) and I want to create plot for each one (result_a.pdf, result_b.pdf - or similar). The plot is the same but the input file is different and the output file is different. Is there a way I can run a loop, pass the parameter names from the outside and save the output with a distinctive name?

Assume that my code for creating the plot -

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}, xtick style={draw=none}}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\newcommand\param{a}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\footnotesize
    \begin{semilogxaxis}
\addplot[color=red,mark=triangle] table [x=x,y=y,col sep=comma, mark=*] {result_\param.csv}; 
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are working under a Linux Distro or under a Mac OS, you may use a shell script to create result_a.tex, result_b.tex, ... and within the same script compile the tex files for the desired output pdfs. Maybe under Windows too you can adopt a similar approach.

Comment: Thanks @Eddymage, I am working with mac os, can you hint me about the script please

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, to make it the clearest possible.

Comment: another possible approach could be to have only a single tex document which loops over all the cvs files and uses the tikz externalise library to produce individual files for each plot.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your file is called `document.tex`, you can pass the name of the csv file to the document by compiling with the following command

```
pdflatex -jobname="document-b" "\\newcommand*\\version{b}\\input{document}"
```

and the document:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

% setting a default value in case it is compiled without the newcommand
\unless\ifdefined\version
\def\version{a}
\fi


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}, xtick style={draw=none}}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\newcommand\param{a}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\footnotesize
    \begin{semilogxaxis}
\addplot[color=red,mark=triangle] table [x=x,y=y,col sep=comma, mark=*] {result_\version.csv}; 
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, I did not know this option for `pdflatex`! Nonetheless, you still need a loop (e.g. in a bash shell script) to create different tex files from different .csv files, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you are working under a Linux Distro or under a Mac OS, you may use a shell script. 
Let `init.tex` be the tex file with

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}, xtick style={draw=none}}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\newcommand\param{a}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\footnotesize
    \begin{semilogxaxis}
\addplot[color=red,mark=triangle] table [x=x,y=y,col sep=comma, mark=*] {
```

and let `ends.tex` be the file containing

```
}; 
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The following script reads each .csv file, puts its contents in a tex file organized as follows:

- `init.tex`
- `result_x.csv`
- `ends.tex`

produces the tex file `result_xx.tex` and compiles it, providing the file `result_xx.pdf`

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(ls *.csv)
do
    a=$(basename -s .csv $i)
    cp init.tex $a.tex
    echo $i >> $a.tex
    cat ends.tex >> $a.tex
    pdflatex $a.tex

done
```

It is a naive solution, there are more experienced than me bash--script writers here in SO, but it should work.

PS. Remember to make the script executable to make it work:

```
chmod 755 myscript.sh
```

See for example [here](https://www.shellscript.sh/).